# Firebase cloud function deployment webhook

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to get notified (webhook or something) when someone deploy a Firebase **cloud function**. Also I would like to know who is deploying that function or may be history of deployed cloud function.

Firebase provides history for web hosting but I'm not able to find anything similar for cloud function in **Firebase console** as well as **GCP console**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no webhook or history for function deployments.  Please feel free to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).